# Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: exclude folder

Tags: git, magento2

I have this error however am unsure how to go about fixing it in the current situation.

I have tried to use git for deployment with Magento 2 which works fine for minor changes however i attempted a version update. I removed the folders vendor and lib from gitignore and attempted the update on development machine and pushed to production. This had a lot of errrors so i reverted the filesystem and just updated manually.

Now however am unsure how to git pull without this error.

Should i just stash the changes or will this mess up the update? I basically want to ignore some folders or something so the update changes are still present but i can also merge my latest changes.

Comment: Well go with the error message.  If you merge you would overwrite what you have locally, so which version of things do you want, your current branch, or the branch being merged in?

Comment: The one being merged in, i just dont want to undo the update while doing it. Both instances have been updated independent of each other tho so should have same files.

Comment: Well if it were my problem, I would just do the merge, and then use the history of both parents to patch anything Git did which I didn't like.  If you are not so comfortable using Git, this approach might not be best.

Comment: I can try both are just test environments that are backed up anyway so good place to play. How do i force the merge however? Do i just stash and then pull?

Comment: I recant what I said earlier.  I think the issue is that you have one or more local files or folders which are NOT versioned by Git but some of these files/folders ARE versioned by Git in the other branch.

Comment: This was possibly caused by messing around with your gitignore file in one branch but not the other.  What I said earlier still does apply though, but you have less freedom.  If you pull, Git will only overwrite your local unversioned files/folders.

Comment: Ok yeah possibly. Is there a way i can just copy the gitignore up and then refresh what files are tracked? Then it should ignore the setup folder where majority of files with issues are showing

Comment: First question: Do you know, for each file or folder in potential conflict, whether it should or should not be versioned?  Unversioning something is a bit of work, and not something you do willy-nilly.

Comment: Well i added them to versioning so i could potentially run the update over git. I'm not going to do this now however so will now figure that when i need to update i will do it manually on the production server so will just remove the folders that are updated from tracking so i can do these updates without this issue again.

Comment: If you want to keep your local untracked files, just back them up, delete them, then do the pull.  After this, overwrite them with what you saved to file.  Ugly?  Yes, but it should work.  The issue here is that the untracked files are completely outside of Git, so tricks like stashing aren't available.

Comment: Yeah that sounds a little messy. I maybe should of spent a bit longer getting the update to work over git then i wouldnt be in this mess!

Comment: Well I think I explained the problem so at least you aren't flying blind.

Comment: Yeah i shall see what i can do thanks for your help